# Erro undefined reference ao tentar usar uma classe template

Tags: c++, ponteiro, template

Tenho uma **classe template Conjunto** e uma **classe Menu** ambas com seus respectivos .cpp e .hpp, ao tentar usar um ponteiro da classe conjunto na minha classe Menu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Trabalho04 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\src\Menu.o||In function `ZN4MenuC2Ev':|
C:\Trabalho04\src\Menu.cpp|5|undefined reference to        `Conjunto<int>::Conjunto()'|
obj\Debug\src\Menu.o||In function `ZN4Menu5opcaoEv':|
C:\Trabalho04\src\Menu.cpp|22|undefined reference to     `Conjunto<int>::criaConjunto()'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Conjunto.hpp

```
template <class T>
class Conjunto {
public:
    Conjunto();
    void criaConjunto();
    virtual ~Conjunto();

private:
    Conjunto<int> * conjunto;
    T * elementos;
    int qtd;
    int tam;
};
```

Conjunto.cpp

```
#include "Conjunto.hpp"
#include "Bibliotecas.hpp"

template <class T>
Conjunto<T>::Conjunto() {
    elementos = new T[10];
    qtd = 0;
    tam = 10;
}

template <class T>
void Conjunto<T>::criaConjunto(){
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    if(conjunto!=NULL) {
        conjunto = NULL;
        delete conjunto;
    }
    if(num == 0) {
        conjunto = new Conjunto<int>();
    } else {
        conjunto = new Conjunto<int>(num);
    }
}

template <class T>
Conjunto<T>::~Conjunto() {
    delete [] elementos;
    elementos = NULL;
}
```

Menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.hpp"

Menu::Menu() {
    conjunto = new Conjunto<int>();
}

void Menu::opcao() {    
    int opcao = 0;
    do {
        opcao = menu();
        switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                conjunto->criaConjunto();
            break;
            case 2:
                //Sair
            break;            
        }
    } while(opcao != 2);
}
```

Menu.hpp

```
#include "Conjunto.hpp"

class Menu {
    public:
        Menu();
        int menu();
        void opcao();
        virtual ~Menu();

    //private:
        int tam;
        Conjunto<int> * conjunto;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código em si está correto, o problema está na organização de arquivos e na forma como o compilador funciona, especialmente com funções e classes template.

funcs.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
T f(const T& obj) { return obj; }

int g(int x) { return x; }
```

Esse arquivo define duas funções, a `g` e a `f<T>`, mas funções template não podem realmente ser compiladas enquanto o T for desconhecido. Vendo apenas esse arquivo não há nenhum uso da função `f`, nenhum valor para `T`. A única coisa que será compilada aqui é `g`. Agora o main:

main.cpp:

```
// isso estaria no seu header:
// ao incluir você **afirma** para o compilador que essas funções já
// existem em algum outro arquivo, ele confiará nessa afirmação.
template <typename T> T f(const T& obj);
int g(int x);

int main() {
    return f(5) + g(4); // f<int> é usado aqui, mas nesse arquivo não temos
                        // a definição de f<T>, então só dá para supor que
                        // f<int> vai estar em outro arquivo.
}
```

No fim, quando compilar todo o programa, **ninguém** terá compilado a função `f<int>`. funcs.cpp não sabia que precisava de `T=int`, e main.cpp nem tinha a definição para poder compilar.

Duas soluções:

1. Dizer para funcs.cpp que `f<int>` será necessário. Isso se chama *explicit template instantiation*:

   ```
   // Dentro de funcs.cpp:
   template int f<int>(const int& obj); // força T=int a ser compilado.
   ```
2. Fazer com que a definição de `f` esteja disponível para main.cpp também. Essa é a solução mais comum, que é incluir a definição de `f` no header, não no source. Fica assim:

   funcs.cpp:

   ```
   #include <funcs.hpp>
   int g(int x) { return x; }
   ```

   funcs.hpp:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   inline T f(const T& obj) { return obj; } // Repare que o inline é necessário aqui
   ```

   main.cpp:

   ```
   #include <funcs.hpp>

   int main() {
       return f(5) + g(4); // f<int> é necessário aqui, e a definição completa
                           // foi incluida pelo funcs.hpp: será compilado
   }
   ```

Tudo isso também se aplica para funções dentro de classes. A sintaxe para uma explicit template instantiation seria assim:

```
template Conjunto<int>::Conjunto();
template void Conjunto<int>::criaConjunto();
template Conjunto<float>::Conjunto();  // supondo que precise de float no futuro
template void Conjunto<float>::criaConjunto();
```

Mas melhor mesmo é incluir as definições de todas as funções no header de sua classe, sempre lembrando de usar o `inline`. Assim não precisa saber quais são todos os tipos de T que precisará

Comment: Eu entendi sua resposta mas não estou conseguindo aplicar ao meu código, meu erro ocorre aqui `Menu::Menu() {
    conjunto = new Conjunto<int>();
}` ao tentar alocar um ponteiro e o msm ocorre se tentar criar um objeto da classe conjunto. Poderia explicar mais ou dar outro exemplo envolvendo classes?

Comment: Moveu tudo que está no Conjunto.cpp para o final do Conjunto.hpp e adicionou `inline` nas funções?

Comment: Assim funciona perfeitamente, mas gostaria de fazer em arquivos separados `.cpp` e `.hpp` somente para aprendizado (esse e o trabalho final de estrutura de dados), porém se for muito trabalhoso ou complicado de outra forma desse jeito está ótimo. Obrigado pelas dicas até agora.

Comment: @FabricioAndrade, nesse caso, para manter separado, precisa declarar cada função passando os tipos que for usar no final do seu .cpp, tal como meu último exemplo na resposta.